# Need clarity behind the theory of diffraction for a black-body source

Tags: optics, thermal-radiation, diffraction

Attempting to model the diffraction for a black-body source, I have stumbled upon a bit of a conundrum with the mathematics. I am not asking **WHY** the light is diffracted, but instead looking for a detailed analysis of the diffraction itself.

Modelling the diffraction for an image is also well understood in the theory of convolution. Assuming we have an image from a "perfect" instrument, that perhaps has noise unrelated to diffraction, then we can convolve the image with a function representing the diffraction pattern of the instrument (the **point spread function** or **PSF**), see image below.

[image]

The process is mathematically described by a convolution equation of the form:

$$ \text{image} = \text{object} \circledast \text{PSF} $$

What I do not quite understand is **what exactly we are convolving when it comes to a black-body source**. A black-body emits light for all wavelengths, and our PSF, say for example the Airy disc, is itself wavelength-dependent.

From my understanding of this then, to correctly model the diffraction, first we must convolve the radiance with the PSF (say from a circular aperture), and only then integrate the radiance for the bandwidth of wavelengths.

i.e. :   $$B_{\lambda}(\lambda,T) \circledast \text{PSF} = \frac{2\pi hc^2}{\lambda^5}\dfrac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{hc}{k_BT\lambda}\right) -1 } \circledast \left [ \frac{2 J_1(k\,a \sin \theta)}{k\,a \sin \theta} \right ]^2 $$

and so over a range of wavelengths, I expect : $$ \int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2}( B(\lambda,T) \circledast \text{PSF} ) d\lambda = \int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2}\left(\frac{2\pi hc^2}{\lambda^5}\dfrac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{hc}{k_BT\lambda}\right) -1 } \circledast \left [ \frac{2 J_1(k\,a \sin \theta)}{k\,a \sin \theta} \right ]^2\right)d\lambda$$

... essentially, I am asking is the maths above sound and physically correct?

Comment: - Your PSF is, unrealistically, not wavelength dependent. The PSF will be wavelength dependent. Over such a wide wavelength range there should also be chromatic aberration. You should also take the wavelength dependent transmission into account.

Comment: Check-my-work questions are unfortunately off-topic on this site.

Comment: First of all, this isn't a check-my-work question in the sense that I am asking you to check my homework. I am asking you whether my logic is sound, and if not, what should be the appropriate method.

Comment: Also, my PSF is wavelength dependent. k is equal to 2*pi/wavelength.